# How to Draw a Curly Brace on a Chart in Excel Using VB

Tags: excel, vba, charts, shapes

I'm new to VBA with Excel and have been searching for an answer on this issue for hours with no success, so hopefully someone can help me.

I have drawn a chart using VB in Excel 2016. This chart has an XYScatterplot and 2 horizontal dashed lines to indicate a range to the viewer, but I wish to draw a curly brace between the horizontal lines to label what this range means.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
Sub Create_Chart()

Dim co As ChartObject
Dim ct As Chart
Dim sc1 As SeriesCollection
Dim ser1 As Series
Dim intMaxX As Integer
Dim intMinX As Integer
Dim intMaxY As Integer
Dim intMinY As Integer

intMaxX = 20000
intMinX = 0
intMaxY = Range("Sheet1!C25").Value
intMinY = Range("Sheet1!C26").Value

Set co = Sheet2.ChartObjects.Add(Range("K1").Left, Range("K1").Top, 1000, 600)

Set ct = co.Chart

With ct
 'Code for my main XYScatterplot chart is here. This all works fine so I am not including it
End With

'This code draws one of my horizontal dashed lines
With ct.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = ""
    .XValues = Array(intMinX, intMaxX)
    .Values = Array(intMinY, intMinY)
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
End With

'This code draws my other horizontal dashed line
With ct.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = ""
    .XValues = Array(intMinX, intMaxX)
    .Values = Array(intMaxY, intMaxY)
    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
End With

'Then I tried to draw my curly brace. I want it to be placed between the two dashed lines
ct.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightBrace, desired x-coordinate on my graph, intMaxY, 10, (intMaxY - intMinY)).TextFrame.Characters.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Now, this does draw a curly brace, but it is tiny and ends up in the top right corner. It doesn't even seem to be affiliated with my chart at all. How do I affiliate it with my chart, specifically with the exact location of my dashed horizontal lines, which you can see are dependent on values from one of my sheets.

Thank you very much for your help.

Update:
Thanks to the response and a few articles I read elsewhere, this is what I have come up with:

```
Set curlyBrace = ct.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightBrace, ct.PlotArea.InsideLeft, ct.PlotArea.InsideTop, 15, ct.PlotArea.InsideHeight)
curlyBrace.IncrementLeft ct.PlotArea.Left + ct.PlotArea.InsideWidth * 0.96
curlyBrace.IncrementTop ct.PlotArea.InsideHeight - ct.PlotArea.Position
With curlyBrace.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```

Based on this code, I can generate the following picture (I am only showing the dashed horizontal lines and the curly brace)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxqn3.png)

How do I now make the vertical start and end points of my curly brace match the positions of my two horizontal lines?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's (for example) how you'd draw a brace covering all of the plot area:

```
Dim b As Shape

Set b = ct.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightBrace, _
                ct.PlotArea.InsideLeft, _
                ct.PlotArea.InsideTop, _
                ct.PlotArea.InsideWidth, _
                ct.PlotArea.InsideHeight)
```

You just need to apply a little math based on your XY coordinate system, to adjust the position and size as required...

[image]